# How to set JW Player custom header in IOS?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, media-player, jwplayer

I am having problem with jw player. It is not working in iOS devices. I want to set custom header in IOS

```
jwplayer().setup({
    playlist: [{
        sources: [{
            file: 'video.m3u8',
            onXhrOpen: function(xhr, url) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('customHeader', 'HeaderValue');
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: is there any error or wrning message you see in logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't... as far as I've found.

IOS uses the native media player, so the `onXhrOpen` callback is not called. I ran into the same issue trying to serve HLS content.

I tried using a service worker to intercept all HTTP requests to add headers that way, but even though the service worker was indeed working as intended, my custom headers were still not being sent... it seems that Apple's native player was actively disallowing extra headers to be sent this way.

Unfortunately, it's all due to Apple's closed philosophy and generally inferior software implementations to give their users a "unified Apple user experience"... and they own such a large market share, they can get away with it.